# Получение уникальных значений SQL-выборки

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Как сделать следующее - Сделал я запрос на выборку. 
Отобразились данные, но к примеру в столбце '1' - 10 одинаковых значений. 
То есть вывод у меня будет такой 
Столбец 1
   f
   f
   f
и т.д

Как вывести только 1 f, а если к примеру появилось значение a в этом же столбце - отобразить и его.

Comment: Чтобы выбрать уникальные значения, надо использовать оператор DISTINCT:

    SELECT DISTINCT name FROM users

Comment: @Fike, сделайте ваш комментарий ответом

Comment: @mountpoint, автор еще не подтвердил, что это именно то, что ему нужно, и у меня есть представление, что хороший ответ должен подробно объяснять, что творится в коде (как на SO)(а мне всегда лень)

я против ничего не имею, но не думаю, что это нужно

Comment: @Fike, я думаю, что в данном случае с DISTINCT не нужно писать кучу лапши. Вы четко и ясно озвучили решение проблемы (надеюсь это то, что нужно ТС-у)

Answer (score 1):

Для получения уникальных значений в выборке можно воспользоваться двумя способами. Пусть имеется таблица `tbl` со столбцом `name`.

## Группировка значений

Для группировки значений предназначена конструкция `GROUP BY` после которой следует имя столбца. Побочным эффектом группировки является тот факт, что вы получаете только уникальные значения сгруппированного поля

```
SELECT
  name
FROM
  tbl
GROUP BY
  name
```

Основное назначение конструкции `GROUP BY` получение групп записей для применения агрегатных функций, поэтому пуристы часто критикуют данный подход для получения уникальных значений.

## Явный запрос уникальных значений

Для запрос уникальных значений можно указать перед именем столбца ключевое слово `DISTINCT`

```
SELECT
  DISTINCT name
FROM
  tbl
```